# How do I skip the Keep/Cancel dialog for downloads in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

This question is specifically for PDF files, because I work with them all day and have to download 20+ at a time. I use an extension called [Linkclump](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lfpjkncokllnfokkgpkobnkbkmelfefj) which selects all links at one time. Since I disabled the Chrome PDF Viewer, these now automatically download (which I intended).

The only problem is I get 20+ dialogs across the bottom of my screen that ask me if I want to Keep or Cancel my downloads. Seriously? I have to click Keep on every single one of them. This did not happen before in Chrome, the change was added a few versions ago I believe.

Oh, and I'm using Chrome Dev v14.0.803.0.

Comment: You're probably right that this is a new feature. I do not see this behavior in Chrome 13.

Comment: Chrome Dev is now on Version 26.0.1386.0 and I'm still not seeing this functionality from what I can tell, a year and a half later. Any help please?